# Last Non-Zero Value in Array

Tags: arrays, excel, excel-formula, is-empty

How would you identify last non-zero element in an array where the last value of the array is zero or empty cell?

If the last element would contain some sort of value, then you'd be able to write

```
INDEX(1:1,0,COUNTA(1:1))
```

But if i'm looking at range `A1:I1`, how would would the formula have to be written in order the result would be 6?

[image]

Comment: Are they all numbers? Do you want to exclude actual 0 values, or just empty cells?

Comment: I'd like to exclude both - zero and empty cells.

Comment: It may have been better to choose a value other than 6 for `F1`, since the desired output of 6 can refer either to the value or the column number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Last non-empty:

```
=LOOKUP(2,1/(1:1<>""),1:1)
```

Last non-empty, non-zero:

```
=LOOKUP(2,1/(1:1<>0),1:1)
```

Or, more difficult =)

```
=INDEX(1:1,MAX(INDEX((1:1<>0)*(COLUMN(1:1)),)))
```

Comment: It won't work. The result is `LOOKUP(2,1/FALSE;1:1)`, which in the end is `#DIV/O!`

Comment: @energyMax, I can't replicate your error. Works fine on my end.

Comment: The third formula works fine. But I have no clue why the first and second one don't work.

Comment: @energyMax, what is your locale? The `2,1` are two parameters and not a double value. If you have a semi-colon instead of comma to seperate parameters than it would look like: `=LOOKUP(2;1/(1:1<>0);1:1)`. I guess that must be the issue.